# Image Preview with jQuery, How to remove the a href click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

This should not be so complicated:

I am using [Easiest Tooltip and Image Preview Using jQuery](http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery)
I am trying to use this [example](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/02/)

How can disable the click event on the original picture, i just want the tooltip to be displayed (i don't want to allow to click on the picture)

How can this be done?
Thanks!

this is the current style:

```
<style>
#preview{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#333;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
    }
</style>
```

this is the Javascript:

```
this.imagePreview = function(){ 
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.preview").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ this.href +"' alt='Image preview' />"+ c +"</p>");                                
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#preview")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    imagePreview();
});
```

this is the main:

```
<a href="1.jpg" /*class="preview"*/><img src="1s.jpg" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
    $('.preview').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

(if you remove the comment around class="preview")

Comment: You have to either use `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;`. Using them together does not make much sense I think.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the latest version of jQuery:

```
$('selector').click(false);
```

For earlier versions:

```
$('selector').click(function(){return false;});
```

Comment: It is complete in itself. just write "`.preview`" in place of `selector`. Anything else?